# Make table fit the page

Tags: tables

[image]

My table is to wide. Anyone know how to make it fit the page?

This is my code:

```
    \begin{table}[]
\scalebox{0.8}{


\begin{tabular}{llll}
\rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Activity}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Aspects}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Impacts}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Level of influence}} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
Anode production &  &  &  \\ \hline
Energy and anode baking & CO$_2$ emissions & Global warming & Global \\ \hline
Anode butts & Emission of SO$_2$, NO$_x$ and fluorides & Negative impact on air, soil and water & Regional, local \\ \hline
 & Emissions of dust & Poor air quality, human health & Local \\ \hline
 & PAH emissions & Human health, accumulates in marine species (e.g. mussels) & Local \\ \hline
Use of cooling water & Emissons to water & Negative impact on the marine environment & Local \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
Electrolysis, aluminum smelting &  &  &  \\ \hline
Energy and anode consumption & CO$_2$ emissions & Global warming & Global \\ \hline
Anode effects & PFC emissions & Global warming & Global \\ \hline
Anode consumption & SO$_2$ emissions & Environmental acidification, health problems & Regional, local \\ \hline
 & NO$_x$ emissions, fluorides & respiratory diseases,  acid rain & Regional, local \\ \hline
 & Carbon monoxide & ozone precursors & Local \\ \hline
 & SPL &  & Local \\ \hline
 & Metal compounds & Toxic for environment & Local \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
Casting and remelting &  &  &  \\
Energy consumption & CO$_2$ emissions & Global warming & Global \\ \hline
Fuel consumption & SO$_2$ emissions & Environmental acidification, health problems & Regional, local \\ \hline
Burning & NO$_x$ emissions & respiratory diseases,  acid rain & Regional, local \\ \hline
 & Volatile organic compounds & ozone precursors & Local \\ \hline
Skimming & Emission of dross & Toxic for environment & Local \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Try using `tabularx` with it's `X` column, or use the `p{<width>}` column with your `tabular` environment. Both allow multiline-text.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options, it may help!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tick mark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In portrait orientation, with `tabularx` and `cellspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
                    \linespread{0.84}\selectfont}X}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{L}

\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} O{L} >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}O{L}
                                      >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}O{L} 
                                l
                             @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Activity}
    &   \textbf{Aspects}
        &   \textbf{Impacts}
            &   \textbf{\makecell[l]{Level of\\ influence}}    \\
    \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
    \rowcolor{gray!20}
\multicolumn{4}{Ol}{\textbf{Anode production}}   \\
Energy and anode baking
    &   \ce{CO2} emissions
        &   Global warming
            &   Global                              \\
Anode butts
    &   Emission of \ce{SO2}, \ce{NO_x} and fluorides
        &   Negative impact on air, soil and water
            &   Regional, local                     \\
    &   Emissions of dust
        & Poor air quality, human health
            & Local                                 \\
    & PAH emissions
        & Human health, accumulates in marine species (e.g. mussels)
            & Local                                 \\
Use of cooling water
    &   Emissions to water
        &   Negative impact on the marine environment
            &   Local                               \\
    \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
\multicolumn{4}{Ol}{\textbf{Electrolysis, aluminum smelting}}\\
Energy and anode consumption
    &   \ce{CO2} emissions
        &   Global warming
            &   Global                              \\
Anode effects
    &   PFC emissions
        &   Global warming
            &   Global                              \\
Anode consumption
    &   \ce{CO2} emissions
        &   Environmental acidification, health problems
            &   Regional, local                     \\
    &   \ce{NO_x} emissions, fluorides
        &   respiratory diseases, acid rain
            &   Regional, local                     \\
    &   Carbon monoxide
        &   ozone precursors
            &   Local                               \\
    & SPL
        &
            &   Local                               \\
    &   Metal compounds
        &   Toxic for environment
            &   Local                               \\
    \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
\multicolumn{4}{Ol}{\textbf{Casting and remelting}}\\
Energy consumption
    &   \ce{CO2} emissions
        &   Global warming
            &   Global                          \\
Fuel consumption
    &   \ce{SO2} emissions
            & Environmental acidification, health problems
            & Regional, local                   \\
Burning
    &   \ce{NO_x} emissions
        &   respiratory diseases, acid rain
            &   Regional, local                 \\
    &   Volatile organic compounds
        &   ozone precursors 
            & Local                             \\
Skimming
    &   Emission of dross
        &   Toxic for environment
            &   Local                           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum.**
Regarding your comment about width of columns:

Columns `L` widths are set by `>{\hsize=<ratio>. \hsize}`. If `<ratio>` is 1 At this sum of all `<ratio>` had to be equal to number od `L` columns in table. In your case it should be 3 (three):

```
> O{L}                   % <--- ratio is 1
>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}O{L}  % <--- ratio is 0.8
>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}O{L}  % <--- ratio is 1.2
                         -------------------       
                                   sum = 3
```

On this way you can change ratios beteen `L` columns in your table. For example, table is narrowed first column width:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} 
                 >{\hsize=0.6\hsize}O{L} %  0.8
                                    O{L} %  1.0
                 >{\hsize=1.4\hsize}O{L} %  1.2
                                       l
                             @{}}
```

Using this table preamble in above MWE produce:

[image]

**Addendum (2):**
If you like to have justified text in your columns, than don't use `L` column specifier but `X`. To preserve some features of `L` column definition also in in `X` column, you have to choices:

- at each use of `X` add option `>{\hspace{0pt}\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}`
- or defined new column type, for example `Y`, which consider above settings:

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hspace{0pt}\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}X}
% using this, "L" column can be now defined as
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Y}
```

I believe, that now is time, that you make yourself more familiar with table settings. Basics about them you can find in [enter link description here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables). Also helps experimenting with different column types in table.

Comment: Thank You, I really liked your layout. However, when I tried to copy-paste the code, it is not working properly.

Comment: @Lisa, what not work? Provided MWE is tested and result of compilation is presented. So you are change something ...

Comment: I found the problem, thanks for the nice table!

Comment: @Lisa, nice to hear this. Now You have three worked solutions, so you can accept this one, which to your opinion on the best way solve your problem (by clicking on the check mark, which is at top left side of selected answer).

Comment: How can I make the activity column smaller? Any quick fix for this? I have used the table as a template for other tables. However, I need this first column to be smaller (more narrow)

Comment: @Lisa, see addendum to answer.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use >{\hsize= x  \hsize} in front of all three O{L}. However, it did not accept this (where x1+x2+x3 = 3). Say I don't want one column to have ratio 1.

Comment: And also, is it possible to Justify the text in the table, distribute the text evenly between the margins

Comment: @Lisa, yes, it is possible. Instead of `L` just use `X`. However, this is not a very smart idea, since columns are narrow and text will consequently looks (very) ugly. Rathe before try the second addendum to answer, will be added asap.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for all help, Zarko. I tried to look at the webpage, however I could not find the answer on why  >{\hsize= x \hsize} in front of all three O{L} does not work.

Comment: @Lisa, new problem, new question. Please!

Comment: Oh, okay, sorry, I'm new to the forum. I will post a new question!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that does away with the `adjustbox` approach and permits automatic line breaking in all four columns with the help of the `tabularx` package and its eponymous LaTeX environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize%
         \hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L{0.86}L{1.14}L{1.3}L{0.7}}

\rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
\textbf{Activity} & \textbf{Aspects} & 
\textbf{Impacts}  & \textbf{Level of influence} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Anode production}  \\ 
Energy and anode baking & \ce{CO2} emissions & Global warming & Global \\ 
Anode butts & Emission of \ce{SO2}, \ce{NO_x} and fluorides & Negative impact on air, soil and water & Regional, local \\ 
 & Emissions of dust & Poor air quality, human health & Local \\ 
 & PAH emissions & Human health, accumulates in marine species (e.g. mussels) & Local \\ 
Use of cooling water & Emissons to water & Negative impact on the marine environment & Local \\ 
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Electrolysis, aluminum smelting} \\ 
Energy and anode consumption & \ce{CO2} emissions & Global warming & Global \\ 
Anode effects & PFC emissions & Global warming & Global \\ 
Anode consumption & \ce{SO2} emissions & Environmental acidification, health problems & Regional, local \\ 
 & \ce{NO_x} emissions, fluorides & respiratory diseases,  acid rain & Regional, local \\ 
 & Carbon monoxide & ozone precursors & Local \\ 
 & SPL &  & Local \\ 
 & Metal compounds & Toxic for environment & Local \\ 
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Casting and remelting}  \\
Energy consumption & \ce{CO2} emissions & Global warming & Global \\ 
Fuel consumption & \ce{SO2} emissions & Environmental acidification, health problems & Regional, local \\ 
Burning & \ce{NO_x} emissions & respiratory diseases,  acid rain & Regional, local \\ 
 & Volatile organic compounds & ozone precursors & Local \\ 
Skimming & Emission of dross & Toxic for environment & Local \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your table is way too wide for a normal page. As can be seen by the other answers, it's possible to fit it to the page but you end up with a lot of multiline text which is hard to read in a table as you get easily lost. I would thus suggest using the `sidewaystable` environment of the `rotating` package and have the table in landscape format in the document. This also makes it way more readable.

Moreover, I suggest using the `mhchem` package for your chemical formulas like SO<sub>2</sub>.

Last but not least, I allowed myself to reformat the table a bit to increase the readability of both the code and the resulting table.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{mhchem}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \begin{tabular}{
            L{0.2\linewidth}
            L{0.2\linewidth}
            L{0.4\linewidth}
            L{0.2\linewidth}
        }
        \toprule
        
        \textbf{Activity} 
            & \textbf{Aspects} 
            & \textbf{Impacts} 
            & \textbf{Level of influence}\\
        
        \midrule
    
        \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Anode production}}\\
        Energy and anode baking 
            & \ce{CO2} emissions 
            & Global warming 
            & Global\\
    
        Anode butts 
            & Emission of \ce{SO2}, $\ce{NO_x}$ and fluorides 
            & Negative impact on air, soil and water 
            & Regional, local\\
     
            & Emissions of dust 
            & Poor air quality, human health & Local\\
    
            & PAH emissions 
            & Human health, accumulates in marine species (e.g. mussels) 
            & Local\\
    
        Use of cooling water 
            & Emissons to water 
            & Negative impact on the marine environment 
            & Local\\
        
        \midrule
        
        \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Electrolysis, aluminum smelting}}\\
        Energy and anode consumption 
            & \ce{CO2} emissions 
            & Global warming 
            & Global\\
            
        Anode effects 
            & PFC emissions 
            & Global warming 
            & Global\\
            
        Anode consumption 
            & \ce{CO2} emissions 
            & Environmental acidification, health problems 
            & Regional, local\\
            
            & $\ce{NO_x}$ emissions, fluorides 
            & respiratory diseases, acid rain 
            & Regional, local\\
            
            & Carbon monoxide 
            & ozone precursors 
            & Local\\
            
            & SPL 
            &  
            & Local\\
            
            & Metal compounds 
            & Toxic for environment 
            & Local\\
            
        \midrule
            
        \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Casting and remelting}}\\
        Energy consumption 
            & \ce{CO2} emissions 
            & Global warming 
            & Global\\
            
        Fuel consumption 
            & \ce{SO2} emissions 
            & Environmental acidification, health problems 
            & Regional, local\\
            
        Burning 
            & $\ce{NO_x}$ emissions 
            & respiratory diseases, acid rain 
            & Regional, local\\
            
            & Volatile organic compounds 
            & ozone precursors & Local\\
            
        Skimming 
            & Emission of dross 
            & Toxic for environment 
            & Local\\
        
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

---

PS: Please provide a *minimal* **working** example (MWE) document in the future.

Comment: Thank you for reply, what is MWE?

Comment: You're welcome! An MWE is a minimal or minimum working example, *i.e.* a fully compilable document that shows your issue without containing any irrelevant code. Have a look at [this meta thread](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) for more info.

Comment: @Lisa refer https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks about `MWE`...