# Alter the size of the columns of table (tabularx)

Tags: tables, tabularx, columns

How can I alter all columns in the following table? I want the second column not to have ratio 1.

```
\begin{table}[H] 
 \caption{}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} 
                 >{\hsize=0.6\hsize}O{L} %  0.8
                                    O{L} %  1.0
                 >{\hsize=1.4\hsize}O{L} %  1.2
                                       l
                             @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{A}
    &   \textbf{B}
        &   \textbf{C}\\
        \toprule
Some text
    & Some text   
        & Some text\\
    \bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: Writing this did not work:
>{\hsize=0.6\hsize}O{L} 
>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}O{L} 
>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}O{L}

Comment: How is the `O` (or `O{L}`) column type defined?

Comment: Please also clarify what "I want the second column not to have ratio 1" is supposed to entail.

Comment: assuming that O is a variant of X (you do not say) then your total must be 3\hsize, in the question you above 0.6+1+1.4  in the comment you have 0.6+1.2+1.2 which should also be OK. "does not work" does not give many clues. If you got an error provide a _complete_ small test file that demonstrates the error.

Comment: @mico, this is follow up question  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569325/make-table-fit-the-page , where in my answer `O` is defined as: `\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{L}`  and is explained in details how to deal with column widths. Unfortunately it is not clear to me, why this not work for OP. My answer perfectly work.

Comment: @Zarko, I tried again today, and it seems to be working perfectly now, don't know what I did wrong yesterday, but thank you so much anyway for all the help with the table. Let me know if there is any credit button I should mark.

Comment: @Lisa, for comments are not votes. I will close your question as "solved by comments". Happy TeXing :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved by comments.